# Getting functions from import file within a foreach loop

Tags: reactjs

As im new to Reactjs it is hard for me to explain this,  but I am trying to define all pages(components, routes and more) on a different page (routes.js) and looping this on the app.js page in order to build all pages/routes. But the imports of the pages are not working because I didn't defined them on the same page.

When I 'am not using the foreach the pages will load.

```
//app.js
import RC from './constants/Routes';
import {Page1,Page2,Page3} from "./components/pages";// not used here but set in route.js

<Switch>
    {Object.keys(RC).forEach(key=>{
        <Route path={RC[key].route} component={RC[key].component}/>
    })}
</Switch>


//routes.js
export default Object.freeze({
    PAGE1: {
        route: '/page1',
        component: 'Page1'
    },
    PAGE2: {
        route: '/page2',
        component: 'Page2'
    },
    PAGE3: {
        route: '/page3',
        component: 'Page3'
    },
});
```

Comment: Are you literally using a string for the `component` prop as in your `app.js`? Or do you do `PAGE1: { route: "/page1", component: <Page1 /> }`?

Comment: I have tried both, when i am passing it as an object the route will show an empty page with no errors

Comment: you will have to use `component: <Page1 />` as pass that as a `prop`, but I don't quite get what you mean when you say "passing it as an object"